# How to install tagged version of image from gitlab container registry?

Tags: docker, image, gitlab

Quite simply I'm trying to install version 0.40.2 of Gitlab's `terraform-images` image - i.e. this https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/-/tags/v0.40.2

When I try this...

`docker pull registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/stable:0.40.2`

I get this error..

`Error response from daemon: manifest for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/stable:0.40.2 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`

I can docker pull with `:latest` but not with a tagged version. How can I pull the version I'm looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the image [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/container_registry/3236154) with this hash: b1b5b34093e118fac03f5b7480182e266f10a941

And looks like you can download the image with this command:

```
docker pull registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/branches/v0-40-2-1.0:b1b5b34093e118fac03f5b7480182e266f10a941 Trying to pull registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/branches/v0-40-2-1.0:b1b5b34093e118fac03f5b7480182e266f10a941...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 4f4fb700ef54 done
Copying blob 4f4fb700ef54 done
Copying blob 59bf1c3509f3 done
Copying blob ec1fedf378de done
Copying blob ef5ee902a580 done
Copying blob 49525ce67f6d done
Copying config 6d9616f034 done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
6d9616f034736e2903959082b9b51db1ef3274571d55c5e59c584a4356b13480
```

PS: I'm not sure if the image is the same, the are three "0-40-2" images: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/container_registry/?orderBy=UPDATED&sort=desc&search%5B%5D=0-40-2&search%5B%5D=

Answer (score 1):

What you've found is a tag on the code, it hasn't been built into an image yet. When you go to [Packages and registries - Container Registry](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/container_registry), you can see a list of built images ready to be pulled. Click on the version you like and then select the copy icon next to the tag. For example:

```
docker pull registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/branches/v0-50-1-1.3:82d2998d95b3f067a476a5d2f4d55980e6533750
```

If there is no image version you want, then you can build it yourself.
Just pull the tagged code, and run `docker build .`.